# confirm form resubmission - Django fixing through redirect

Tags: python, django

I'm getting a form resubmission error when I refresh a page or submit back button..to prevent this after the post request, Im redirecting it to a new page that will display the actual page...when I do that...I get the below error after I click the submit button on the mainpge.html

Error:
    NoReverseMatch at /startpage/

```
Reverse for 'testpage' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found.
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, redirect
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
from django.template import Context, RequestContext
@csrf_exempt
def mainpage(request):
    return render_to_response('mainpage.html')

@csrf_exempt
def startpage(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       print 'post', request.POST['username']
    else:
       print 'get', request.GET['username']
    variables = RequestContext(request,{'username':request.POST['username'],
           'password':request.POST['password']})
    #return render_to_response('startpage.html',variables)
    return redirect('testpage')

def testpage(request):
    variables = {}
    return render_to_response('startpage.html',variables)
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',mainpage),
    url(r'^startpage',startpage),
```

startpage.html

```
<html>
<head>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input type="submit" id="test1" value="mainpage">
This is the StartPage
Entered user name ==   {{username}}
Entered password  == {{password}}
</body>
</html>
```

mainpage.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
This is the body
<form method="post" action="/startpage/">{% csrf_token %}
Username: <input type="text" name="username">
Password: <input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" value="Sign with password">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect), `redirect` takes either of the following three:

1. A model: the model’s `get_absolute_url()` function will be called.
2. A view name, possibly with arguments: `urlresolvers.reverse` will be used to reverse-resolve the name.
3. An absolute or relative URL, which will be used as-is for the redirect location.

By passing a string not started with a protocol and doesn't contain slashes, the argument is recognised as a name, and is passed into `reverse`.

The wording is maybe a bit misleading here. [`reverse`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/urlresolvers/#django.core.urlresolvers.reverse) looks up a view by its *URL pattern name*, so when the document says that it takes **a view name** it actually means **the name of a URL pattern that points to a view**, not the name of the view itself. Since `reverse` looks in your `urlpatterns` (in `urls.py`) for URL patterns, you need to add `testpage` into it so that it can be found by `reverse`:

```
url(r'^whatever/$', testpage, name='testpage')
```

Obviously you can put any pattern you wish in the first argument, and need to import the view function for the second argument. The `name` part is what `reverse` uses to look up the URL.